# MySQL doesn't use entire index when combining join and range

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance, sqlperformance

I'm trying to optimize a simple query that joins between two tables and applies a range condition.
From the explain plan below, you can see that the index *inv_quantity_on_hand* is only used partially (4 bytes, only for the first column - *inv_item_sk*). I would expect the entire index to be used, as the second part (*inv_quantity_on_hand*) of the index is used in the WHERE clause in a range condition.

Please note that this happens only with a join and a range condition. Replacing the range condition to a constant equality comparison (inv_quantity_on_hand = 5) will change the explain plan and MySQL will use the entire index.

It seems to be an instance of this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8569.

I checked it with MySQL 5.7 and it still happens. Anyone can think of a good workaround please?

**Schema structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
    `inv_date_sk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `inv_item_sk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `inv_warehouse_sk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `inv_quantity_on_hand` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`inv_date_sk` , `inv_item_sk` , `inv_warehouse_sk`),
    KEY `inv_w` (`inv_warehouse_sk`),
    KEY `inv_i` (`inv_item_sk`),
    KEY `inv_quantity_on_hand_index` (`inv_item_sk` , `inv_quantity_on_hand`),
    CONSTRAINT `inv_d` FOREIGN KEY (`inv_date_sk`)
        REFERENCES `date_dim` (`d_date_sk`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `inv_i` FOREIGN KEY (`inv_item_sk`)
        REFERENCES `item` (`i_item_sk`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `inv_w` FOREIGN KEY (`inv_warehouse_sk`)
        REFERENCES `warehouse` (`w_warehouse_sk`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8

CREATE TABLE `item` (
    `i_item_sk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `i_item_id` CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `i_rec_start_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_rec_end_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_item_desc` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_current_price` DECIMAL(7 , 2 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_wholesale_cost` DECIMAL(7 , 2 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_brand_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_brand` CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_class_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_class` CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_category_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_category` CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_manufact_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_manufact` CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_size` CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_formulation` CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_color` CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_units` CHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_container` CHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_manager_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `i_product_name` CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`i_item_sk`),
    KEY `item_color_index` (`i_color`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    inventory
        INNER JOIN
    item ON inventory.inv_item_sk = item.i_item_sk
WHERE
    inventory.inv_quantity_on_hand > 100
        AND item.i_color = 'red';
```

**Execution plan:**

```
# id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys                    | key                        | key_len | ref                  | rows | filtered |  Extra
-----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------
1    | SIMPLE      | item      |            | ref  | PRIMARY,item_color_index         | item_color_index           | 61      | const                | 384  | 100.00   |  
1    | SIMPLE      | inventory |            | ref  | inv_i,inv_quantity_on_hand_index | inv_quantity_on_hand_index | 4       | tpcds.item.i_item_sk | 615  |  33.33   | Using where; Using index
```

Comment: There's no actual problem, you think that MySQL should "use" entire index, there's no issue, no workaround and everything is just fine. That's how it works with range. I'm unsure why you're even asking this question, is there an actual problem except you wanting that MySQL's explain yields different statistics?

Comment: Yes, I think there is a problem. I'll provide an example with dates as it might be simpler - let's assume the range would have filtered the data to only the last month's data, so using the index could have done that easily. Instead, all year's data should now be scanned. Same in the query above, there is an index and MySQL doesn't use part of it, without any good reason I can understand.

Comment: There is no problem. You can't throw indexes around and expect MySQL does something magic with it and use "less" or "more" of it. Your condition is "*where item.i_color = 'red' AND inventory.inv_quantity_on_hand > 100*" - what exactly do you think MySQL has to do? Accurately know, without any sort of operation, which exact records are the ones that are larger than 100 and `red`? Indexes aren't magic, it's a simple ordered data structure, you can't expect it to work with ranges the same as with equality operator. There's no actual problem here, it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Maybe I didn't explain myself properly. When looking at the the conditions applied on the inventory table, the ON clause uses inv_item_sk and the WHERE clause uses inv_quantity_on_hand. So, I'm not sure I yet seen an explanation on why MySQL would choose not to use the exact same index that would allow it to search on both of those columns in full (inv_quantity_on_hand_index), but instead choose that same index and use only the first part of it? By the way, replacing the range operator with an equals operator will get MySQL to use the full index.

Answer (score 0):

The multi column indexes are stored as concats of the different columns.
I think MySQL will not evaluate a substring within a multi column index for comparison.  When you use inv_quantity_on_hand = 5 (or in(1,2,3,4,5)) MySQL will build the strings from your input for comparison so it can use the full index. Using between or > basically provides an unlimited number of possible substrings to compare (before checking data type). Building all those strings and comparing them would take much more time than using the index for the first column (on-clause) and then check the inv_quantity_on_hand "using where".

Comment: Thank you, but the relevant columns in in the inventory table are all numeric. No strings involved in that table.

Comment: MySQL Documentation states under 8.3.5 Multiple-Column Indexes: "A multiple-column index can be considered a sorted array, the rows of which contain values that are created by concatenating the values of the indexed columns." 
After concatenating the values of the indexed columns, the result will probably stored as a string (how else could MySQL concatenate two integers without building a string?)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When checking the same condition and replacing the range condition with an "equals" condition, the multi column index is used. It seems like an issue with only join + range condition, which doesn't add up with the implementation from section 8.3.5 the way I understood it.

Comment: Yes, the issue should only comes up when using a range condition. I'm happy that i could help you. On a second note, you might be able to add a  column or several to flag all records that exceed your thresholds (in this case >100) and update them dynamically (but it depends on the table, usage and environment). Then make the flag-column part of the key or add as many keys as you need to cover all flag columns (with a big table , high usage and several flag-columns this could become inconveniently, but with smalle tables [<10 millions] and only a few flag-columns this should work nicely)

Answer (score -1):

use BETWEEN condition instead of conditional operator

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. Same execution plan. Thanks anyways :)